# Manage user permission with an instance variable or in a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, coding-style

I'm looking for the cleanest way to handle a user permission. It would be used to define if a menu option can be displayed (menu is present in all views) and the access to a page.
So I was wondering which is the cleanest way to do it.

1. Set an instance variable in each action from the controller validating if the user had access
2. Add a method in the application helper validating each time it is call if the current user have access

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to implement an administrator or something similar? I think the cleanest way would be to just make a new column in the users table, which is initialized to false for most, but to true if the user is an admin (or something else). Then you can just make two partials to handle the two cases.

In that case, in your menu view (in your layout or whatnot) you would have this code or something similar:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
    <%= render 'admin_page' %>
<% else %>
    <%= render 'user_page' %>
<% end %>
```

Where I assume you define @current_user in your controller, or if you are using Devise, this is handled automatically.

Edit: Yes I endorse the earlier answer, CanCan is a good gem to handle these things also, you should consider using it. In such a case your code would look something like:

```
<% if can? :update, @user %>
  # Edit something 
  <%= link_to edit_profile_path(@user), class: 'user' do %>
    Edit your profile
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define method in your `ApplicationController` who will check current user permissions. And you can use that method in `before_action` callback for those actions you need it.

I would recommend to look at [cancancan gem](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) (it's community driven support of cancan gem)

Using it it's easy to [authorize actions](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions) and [check abilities](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Checking-Abilities) to decide show menu item or not.

You can also check out [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) about that subject to get understanding of whole idea.